# The embedded manifest is invalid or could not be read

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-updates

while running Android debug build in real device app crashing in device with error is

> The embedded manifest is invalid or could not be read. Make sure you have configured expo-updates correctly in android/app/build.gradle. app.manifest

Actually, I developed an app with Expo bare flow with expo updates but I did proper expo update installation in my project. The error related to expo updates any suggestions to fix this issue

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? currently running into the same issue.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling expo-update since we weren't using it

Answer (score 2):

Just leave these expo update tags in the manifest. That's what solved it for me

```
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="46.0.0"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@projet/projet"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL" android:value="default"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
```

Previously it was like this

```
 <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="46.0.0"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@projeto/projet"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_RELEASE_CHANNEL" android:value="default"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved that by running

```
eas update:configure
```

as suggested in https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21238

Im using 'expo' sdk 49.0.0

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need expo-updates in your project, you can resolve the issue by uninstalling expo-updates:

```
npm uninstall expo-updates
```

Sentry is not requiring expo-updates anymore in their latest versions, as pointed out in [this comment](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21238#issuecomment-1658919322).